# TCP Worker Role to Web Role Communication

Tags: azure, webrole

I am new to Azure platform.

I am able to connect with the webrole.

Now how can i send data from the Worker Role, to the Web Role to display on the Website?

And how can i display the continuous TCP data which the WebRole gets, without refreshing the page or starting over?

Thanks for your Help

Answer (score 1):

You can communicate directly between roles via their internal endpoints.

For more:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg433033.aspx

When it comes to the worker role pushing notifications to the web role then I suggest you look into node.js for Azure.

For more: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2011/12/16/node-js-in-windows-azure-to-the-cloud-and-beyond.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The best way to send data from the worker role to the web role is to have the worker role write some data to table/blob storage and have the web role poll periodically for changes to this data.

What do you mean display continuous TCP data?  Do you mean like streaming a video?  Two methods for that are AJAX polling or to use flash.

Comment: Hi Ryan, Thanks for the Reply. I am sending sensor data from my Mobile phone to Azure Worker Role by TCP. I want to display the continuous stream of Sensor data recieved by the server.

Comment: You'll have to set up a TCP endpoint and specify the port in which you want to allow connection. This tutorial should get you started with everything you need to do about communication in Windows Azure.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/WAZPlatformTrainingCourse_WindowsAzureRoleCommunicationVS2010Lab

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the data you want to transfer.

For messaging between Worker and Web roles you can use [Queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179363.aspx). the size of the messages is limited to 8k. if you need bigger data to be transferred, you should use Table/Blob Storage, and pass the address to the table storage via Queues.